# map is not a function its may be due to array

Tags: reactjs, api

- > items.map() is not a function
  > its harrassing me since last 5 hours
  > i am new in reactjs  please help me
  > it like headache for me
  > it may be due to state is not set properly
  > if anyone have solution please help

```
    class QuestionAPI extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log(props)
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [],
    };
  }
  //Question answer api call
  componentDidMount = () => {
    axios.get(apiURL, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer  ` + token,
      },
    }).then((result) => {
      //  console.log(result.data);
      this.setState({items:result}) 
       //error is hear
         this.state.items.map((item) =>
           //QuestionAPI container
          this.props.QuestionApiHandler({ id: item.id }))
   })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}
export default QuestionAPI;
```

Comment: could you show what is in result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- i think this may work
- I hope it helps you.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    axios.get(apiURL, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer  ` + token,
      },
    }).then(response => response.data)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ items: data })
        this.state.items.map((item) =>
          this.props.QuestionApiHandler({ id: item.id })
        )
```